# Find the product of a sum in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to know how to calculate the product of the sum of a set of cells while being nested in a IF function. I have already tried `=IF(=sum(B2:E2)>10000, =sum(B2:E2)*0.05, =sum(B2:E2)*0.02)` but it is not working.

Comment: If I'm following what you want to do, you're close.  The only equal sign should be at the beginning.  Remove the equal signs before each SUM.

Comment: yeah, what fixer1234 said. `=IF(sum(B2:E2)>10000, sum(B2:E2)*0.05, sum(B2:E2)*0.02)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the other guys answered in comments, but they're quite right: remove the equals signs before each of the SUMs and it should work as you expect.